# Convert node module resolution to "fully specified" with Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript module that needs to work in node and the browser. I use `import myModule from './myModule'` throughout and when I import my module in `create-react-app` I get this error:

> 'BREAKING CHANGE: The request './myModule' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified'.

Is there a Typescript settings to be able to convert my "not fully specified" to "fully specified" during compilation?

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/recommended/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["./src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2020",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I stumbled upon the same problem these days. The problem is that ES modules need fully specified relative imports and exports. They won't accept something like:

```js
import x from "./mymodule"
```

They must have an extension, either `.js` or `.mjs` or `.cjs` as this [typescript reference page shows](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html) explains.

The problem is that tsc, the Typescript compiler, does not convert our imports into fully specified ones. And if we fully specify our imports like this `import x from "./mymodule.ts"` tsc will keep the `.ts` extension on the import of the compiled file but the `./mymodule` file will already be converted to a `./mymodule.js` with a `.js` extension.

There are well known debates in related issues requests opened for the tsc team on GitHub [#27481](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27481) and [#11901](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11901), but with no resolutions.

So, what I did was to build a script called [fix-tsc-es-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fix-tsc-es-imports) using ShellJS sed to convert all relative imports and exports from the outDir of the tsconfig.json file, into fully specified. It can be integrated into the build process after tsc.

There are other possible solutions, as for instance to add a rule so Prettier won't complain about fully specified extensions and change all your relative imports and exports to a `.js` extension. But I think that is too overwhelming.

Another solution is to manually use VS Code regex substitution, but that can lead to errors as the process will not be automated and you will need to fill the regex every time a tsc compilation is triggered.